# An attempt was made to set a report parameter that is not defined in this report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!IsPostBack)
  {
    var parameter = new ReportParameter("store", Request.QueryString["id"],false);
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(parameter);

    var ds = new ReportDataSource("AccountingSMSDataSet", 
      BalanceReport.GetData(int.Parse(parameter.ToString())));
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ds);
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get an error :

> An attempt was made to set a report parameter 'store' that is not
>   defined in this report.

I want to know what is the problem and I am sending my querystring from mvc page and get my value that I used in my querystring from drop down list.

Please anyone know the problem, please tell me.

Comment: As the exception tells you - the report you're trying to run doesn't have the parameter "store" defined in report definition.

Comment: I know the exception and i don't understand why code make this exception @ Ondrej Svejdar

Comment: Can you share the report definition ? (rdl file)